# AutomationAnywhere JavaScript multiple variables output

Tags: javascript, rpa, automationanywhere

I am trying to return multiple variable as an output from js Script in AutoamtionAnywhere. 
For example I have js script like this:

```
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday'];
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'August', 'September', 'October' , 'November', 'December'];
var d = new Date();
var week_day = days[d.getDay()+2];
var day_number = d.getDate();
var month_name = months[d.getMonth()];
var month_number = d.getMonth();
if(month_number <= 9){
    month_number.toString()
    month_number = "0" + month_number
};

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(week_day, day_number, month_name, month_number);
```

In AAE I am also putting 4 different variables as an output
(With comas and with only spaces): 
[image]

After running BOT I am receiving following error: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return value in "Run Script" command will not support multiple variables.

For such requirement you can return value by concatenating with some character.

You can create script like this.

```
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("ReturnValue1#ReturnValue2");
```

Your bot should fetch this value in one variable(say $Prompt-Assignment$) and then you can split it with string operator and assign it in some list variable.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have also choose to do that it this way, but if I could get multiple vars from scripts BOT code would me much cleaner. I hope in next version they will give as possibility to take multiple vars from one script without using String Operations ...

Comment: True, multiple vars option will reduce complexity of string operations and  BOT code will be clean.